# DRF spectacular creates tags, can't figure out where to remove(

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class EquipmentViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Equipment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EquipmentSerializer

    @extend_schema(
        summary='Получение списка всех объектов класса "Оборудование"',
        tags=['Equipment'],
        description="""
        Получение списка всех оборудования.
        В ответе будет получен полный список объектов класса "Оборудование".
        """,
        request=EquipmentSerializer,
        responses=equipment_status_codes
    )
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In the swager, in addition to tags=['Equipment'], tag = v1 is created where /api/v1/equipment/{id}/ is located.
I tried everything, I want to cry, extend_schema_view doesn't help in any way